# Mathaccents, fontdimens, macros, oh my!

Tags: macros, tex-core, accents

Why doesn't this work?

```
\def\circacc{%
  \dimen0=\fontdimen5\textfont2
  \fontdimen5\textfont2=-.5ex
  \mathaccent\circ
  \fontdimen5\textfont2=\dimen0
}$\circacc a$\bye
```

The last line produces an error (`! Missing { inserted.`), but why on earth when it worked *just two lines ago*?!

If I change the macro to include an argument I can get it to work, but then the last `\fontdimen`-change gets applied before the accent has been typeset!

I'm afraid I'm on TeX Wizard -lands now, and I'm lost.

---

**Update**: The first part of the question is now clear to me. However, the grouped version didn't work for me for the second (w/ args), is there something I'm still missing?

```
\def\circacc#1{
  \dimen0=\fontdimen5\textfont2 \dimen1=\fontdimen5\scriptfont2 \dimen2=\fontdimen5\scriptscriptfont2
  {\fontdimen5\textfont2=-.25ex \fontdimen5\scriptfont2=-.25ex \fontdimen5\scriptscriptfont2=-.25ex
  \mathaccent\circ{#1}}
  \fontdimen5\textfont2=\dimen0 \fontdimen5\scriptfont2=\dimen1 \fontdimen5\scriptscriptfont2=\dimen2
}$\circacc W$\bye
```

(produces the accent with the original x-height)

Comment: As always please provide a minimal example even/especially if it is more or less trivial. Also stating the exact error would be great.

Comment: @Martin: better now?

Comment: Yes, much better. Thanks. In general you should also add that it should be compiled with plainTeX.

Comment: @Martin: I don't see anyone mentioning that they should compile with LaTeX in other questions. Discrimination! `;-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between \accent and the character to be accented assignments can intervene; not between \mathaccent and the atom to be accented. Since TeX expects either a math character or a subformula and `\fontdimen` isn't a character, it tries to insert a brace.

The first idea would be to define `\circacc` with an argument and do the reassignment after having typeset the accented symbol:

```
\def\circacc#1{%
  \dimen0=\fontdimen5\textfont2
  \fontdimen5\textfont2=-.5ex
  \mathaccent\circ{#1}
  \fontdimen5\textfont2=\dimen0
}
```

This, unfortunately, fails: the two assignments do nothing, since TeX converts a math list into a horizontal list when the math list is finished and so when the `\fontdimen` is again what was before. One has to add a group *and* convert the math list to a horizontal list:

```
\def\circacc#1{%
  \dimen0=\fontdimen5\textfont2
  \hbox{$\fontdimen5\textfont2=-.5ex
        \mathaccent\circ{#1}$}
  \fontdimen5\textfont2=\dimen0
}
```

The reassignment to `\fontdimen5` has to be redone, since assignments to a `\fontdimen` are inherently global (they are <*font assignments*>, TeXbook p. 277).

Of course this doesn't work for `$a_{\circacc{W}}$`, for example, so I wouldn't recommend this approach: the accents package does this in a safer way.

Comment: Thanks for the critic :-) I was just pointing out that the error would disappear when using an argument but didn't looked further into the task.

Comment: Hmm, if I'm reading you right, you are saying that the grouped version should work, right? But I only get the original x-height for `\circacc`. I'll update the question.

Comment: @morbusg: you're right, there was a small error. :( A `\hbox` is necessary.